# Thoughts on console.log/catch on webpage using socket.io/express.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Now trying to learn socket.io, and only able to find chat related tutorials around.

My approach is an app to log all "server" debug code (console.log, try/catch) remotely on a web page.

Its a very simple implementation (one way communication), a buffer could be implemented avoiding losing logs, a more robust way to show objects/arrays could be nice, and a few more changes...

Expert review required :) and suggestions always welcome.

```
// server.js
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
app.io = require("socket.io").listen(http);
const logWeb = require("./logweb")(app)      // web log component

// testing
logWeb('testing');
logWeb({ txt: 'obj testing' });

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5002);
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("working!") );
http.listen(app.get('port'), () => logWeb("live on: http://localhost:" + app.get('port')));
```

```
// logweb.js
"use strict";
module.exports = (app) => {
  const io = app.io.of("/logs");
  const getHandle = (req, res) => res.render("index");    // ejs template
  app.get("/logs", getHandle);

  const sendData = (msg) => {
    io.on("connection", (cli) => {
      const isObj = (x) => x instanceof Object && x.constructor === Object;
      const data = isObj(msg) ? JSON.stringify(msg, undefined, 2) : msg;
      const ts = new Date().toLocaleString("sv").replace(" ", "_");
      let out = { ts: ts, msg: data }
      cli.emit('log', out);
      console.log(out);
    });
  };
  return (msg) => sendData(msg);
};
```

```
// index.ejs
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div {
        border: 1px solid powderblue;
        padding: 2px 8px 2px 8px;
        margin: 4px 0px 2px 0px;
        font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
        font-size: 11px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      const nsp = "/logs"; // namespace
      const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5002" + nsp);

      socket.on("log", (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        logLine(data);
      });

      const logLine = (data) => {
        let line = document.createElement('div');
        line.innerHTML = `${data.ts}: ${data.msg}`; 
        let parent = document.getElementById('tail');
        parent.insertBefore(line, parent.firstChild);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id='tail'>
      <div>logServer started!</div>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```